# Downgrade NG2 Directive to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-directive

So as far as I know we can downgrade NG2 Components & Services into AngularJS.
But I'm wondering if it's possible to do that for NG2 Directives?

I read the upgrade/downgrade guides already but I couldn't find anything.
I found the way to upgrade AngularJS Directives but not the other way around!

Something like this but for directive (This is for components):

```
angular.module('heroApp', [])
  .controller('MainController', MainController)
  .directive('heroDetail', downgradeComponent({
    component: HeroDetailComponent,
    inputs: ['hero'],
    outputs: ['deleted']
  }) as angular.IDirectiveFactory);
```

Any help?

Answer (score -1):

So apparently we don't need to downgrade a NG2 Directive. Just add it as a declaration into your application and it will work.