# Downgarde angular 2 directive or at least being able to use it in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm trying to use my ng2 directive in angularjs, but cannot get it to work. I've seen that downgradeComponent uses restric: 'E' for the angularjs directive, which means it's restricted to elements. Anyone knows how to deal with this problem?

I've tried simply using my directive in angular js, and it didn't work.
I'm using UpgradeModule for hybrid bootstraping.

this is my directive.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[test-directive]'
})
export class TestDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input("test-directive") testDirective: string;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("color is = " + this.testDirective);
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'background-color', this.testDirective);
    }
}
```

I've tried using in AngularJS as an attribute (trying using it as [test-directive] and as test-directive.

Am I missing something here? Because I've searched the web and didn't found a lot of information regarding this problem.

Comment: Here is my example from angular tutorial https://plnkr.co/edit/jE4FTbnEWTuuYasXNvEX?p=preview https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#transcluding-angular-content-into-angularjs-component-directives

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in plunker?

Comment: In your example (yurzui) I don't see the use of attribute, I'll try to reproduce it on your example.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/dZaKSNlPjl6M6Jc4bubG?p=preview here is an example take a look at test-attribute, which works in angular2, but not in angular.js (index.html). I tried downgrading the directive, but it cannot be done.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16695

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll find a hack around just like stated in the comment "f you are desperate you could probably hack around it, by using an AngularJS .decorator() to change the directive's restrict to A." made by gkalpak and I'll post it here if it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, in `upgradeAdapter` gives you only `downgradeNg2Provider` and `downgradeNg2Component` and indeed, `downgradeNg2Component` always uses "E". (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/upgrade/src/common/downgrade_component.ts#L70)

Take a look on [Downgrade NG2 Directive to AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855446/downgrade-ng2-directive-to-angularjs). I haven't tested it, but author of the question says, that there is no need to downgrade directive and you can use it out of the box.

Comment: Yeah I saw that and tried just using my angular 2 directive in angular.js, it didn't work. but do you happen to know what PRAISER means by "Just add it as a declaration into your application and it will work"? which application angular 2 or angular.js?